# While iterating over a list, how can I fill the remainder with a number once a condition has been met?

Tags: python

I have an `array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

And say I want to fill in the remainder of my array with 1s, once a certain condition has been met.

For example,

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    i%2 == 0:
        array[i:] = 1
```

The above produces a:

> TypeError: can only assign an iterable.

How can I change my code to achieve the above?

(P.S.: Is it possible to do it with list comprehension?)

**Expected output:**

array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Just added it to the end of my question.

Comment: Index 2 isn't the first even index, though

Comment: Sorry you're right

Comment: There are two questions here. The immediate is for [the mentioned missing 'if'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69482021/while-iterating-over-a-list-how-can-i-fill-the-remainder-with-a-number-once-a-c/69482091#69482091) and the real question is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a slice of the part *before* the insertion point and concatenate a list with that constant value repeated (NB: you need `if`, and you probably want to break out the loop):

```
if <condition>:
    array = array[:i] + [1]*(len(array)-i)
    break
```

Comment: That's so clever, thanks trincot

Comment: Trincot, when you have some time, a follow on question here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508746/how-can-i-fill-the-remainder-of-the-first-column-of-an-n-x-n-matrix-with-1s-on

Comment: This was the purpose of my above question actually

Answer (score 2):

Use a second loop and break the first loop

```
def fill(arr, val, start=0):
    for i in range(start, len(arr)):
        arr[i] = val

for i, _ in enumerate(array):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        fill(array, 1, i)
        break
```

Index 0 is even, though, so you'll end up with all 1s, so just start with that

Otherwise, given a list of zeros and some condition, it should be easy to figure out where that condition is first true. With that value, you can split the list into parts

```
array = ([0] * conditional_index) if conditional_index > 0 else [1]
assert expected_length > conditional_index 
array.extend(1 for _ in range(expected_length - conditional_index + 1))
```