# How can I fill the remainder of the first column of an N x N matrix with 1's, once a certain condition is met in my for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have an `N x N matrix` filled with 0's as follows:

```
str1 = "Patrick"
str2 = "Garrick"

matrix = [[0 for _ in range(len(str1))] for _ in range(len(str2))]
```

I am iterating over the first column of the matrix, and **if a certain condition is met, I would like to fill in the rest of the first column with 1's**, how can I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
for i in range(len(str2)):
    if str2[i] == str1[0]:   #this is the condition!
        matrix[i:][0] = 1
        break
    else:
        matrix[i][0] = 0
```

But the above gives me an error, since we cannot do `matrix[i:][0] = 1`, and I do understand why, but how else can I achieve the above?

Comment: You have explained the process for the first column, but maybe it would be useful to present what the purpose is of the matrix. What do you want the matrix to represent at the very end for this particular input?

Comment: The condition will never be met using your sample strings — I suggest you provide some that will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pure python answer is that you need to iterate:

```
flag = 0
for i in range(len(str2)):
    if str2[i] == str1[0]:
        flag = 1
    matrix[i][0] = flag
```

You can make it simpler by finding the index up front since your matrix is already zeros:

```
try:
    i = str2.find(str1[9])
except:
    pass
else:
    for j in range(i, len(str2)):
        matrix[j][0] = 1
```

You can cheat for the first column (won't work for the rest):

```
try:
    i = str2.find(str1[9])
except:
    pass
else:
    matrix[i:] = [1] + [0 for _ in range(len(str1) - 1)]
```

If you're willing to use numpy, you can do this without looping explicitly, delegating instead to under-the-hood vectorized loops:

```
s1 = np.array(list(str1))
s2 = np.array(list(str2))
matrix = np.maximum.accumulate(s2[:, None] == s1, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want. Note I'm using different strings as input so the conditional will be be met (several times).

```
from pprint import pprint

str1 = "Patrick"
str2 = "GaPPicP"

matrix = [[0 for _ in range(len(str1))] for _ in range(len(str2))]

for i in range(len(str2)):
    if str2[i] == str1[0]:   # this is the condition!
        for j in range(len(str2)):
            matrix[j][i] = 1

pprint(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through `range(i, len(str2))` and assign `1` to `matrix[j][0]`.

**Demo:**

```
str1 = "Patrick"
str2 = "Garrick"

matrix = [[0 for _ in range(len(str1))] for _ in range(len(str2))]
print(matrix)

for i in range(len(str2)):
    if str2[i] == str1[0]:  # this is the condition!
        for j in range(i, len(str2)):
            matrix[j][0] = 1
        break
    else:
        matrix[i][0] = 0

print(matrix)
```

**Note:** For the given strings, your condition will never become `True`. You can test it some other values e.g. with `str1 = "aatrick"`.